# VPN Tunnel between Cisco ASA 5525 & Cisco 1941 Router

Tags: vpn, cisco

Recently I configured a Site-2-Site VPN Tunnel and I'm getting this errors:

```
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= TTL_map.  Map Sequence Number = 1.
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Group = 10.249.7.13, IP = 10.249.7.13, Removing peer from correlator table failed, no match!
3   Feb 27 2018 09:21:57    Group = 10.249.7.13, IP = 10.249.7.13, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0x00007fff383352e0, mess id 0xb3f7fd67)!
```

I did research and applied many solutions they recommended, but there is no result.

> How can I solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try EIGRP. Should work between the 2.